# What could be the cause of extra spaces being left in grid?

Tags: html, css

So this grid I have on my webpage creates empty cells when I add more than a certain number of elements i.e. columns. This works fine if I remove some elements and add others, I have already tried putting the elements after the empty cell in another row, and it still has the same problems. Changing the position of elements changes the position of empty grids.

here is the page : [www.cmata.in/exhibitors.html](http://www.cmata.in/exhibitors.html)

IMPORTANT: It always seems to keep two spaces empty.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

This is the css for the gallery that I'm using :

```
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #e6e9f0 0%, #eef1f5 100%);
    min-height: 100vh;
    font: normal 16px sans-serif;
}

.gallery-container h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 70px;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #58595a;
}

.gallery-container p.page-description {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 30px auto;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #85878c;
}

.tz-gallery {
    padding: 40px;
}

.tz-gallery .thumbnail {
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

.tz-gallery .thumbnail:hover {
    transform: translateY(-10px) scale(1.02);
}

.tz-gallery .lightbox img {
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.tz-gallery .caption{
    padding: 26px 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.tz-gallery .caption h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.tz-gallery .caption p {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #7b7d7d;
    margin: 0;
}

.baguetteBox-button {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: The image in the middle has bigger height and break the flow. Give all a min-height and this could work

Comment: can you share html code as well? did you try adding "display: inline-block;?